# Rails 7: validate_secret_key_base': Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mrsk

**Rails 7.0.4**

When deploying with MRSK I am getting this error

> [linux/arm64 build 10/10] RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile:
> #23 1.053 rails aborted!
> #23 1.053 ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `bin/rails credentials:edit`
> #23 1.053 /rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `'
> #23 1.053 Tasks: TOP => environment
> #23 1.053 (See full trace by running task with --trace)

The line in my Dockerfile that it is stuck on is

```
# Precompiling assets for production without requiring secret RAILS_MASTER_KEY
RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile
```

if I run `EDITOR=emacs bin/rails credentials:edit` I can see that I do have a `secret_base_key` set already in the encrypted credentials file

in my production.rb file, this line is COMMENTED OUT:

```
  # config.require_master_key = true
```

if I UNCOMMENT the above line, the error changes to :

```
 > [linux/arm64 build 10/10] RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile:
#22 0.999 Missing encryption key to decrypt file with. Ask your team for your master key and write it to /rails/config/master.key or put it in the ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY'].
```

But both of these are already true-- there already is a file at `config/master.key` (not in Git) and there already is an env variable for RAILS_MASTER_KEY

As well, my config/deploy.yml file contains:

```
# Configure builder setup.
builder:
  args:
    RUBY_VERSION: "<%= Pathname.pwd.join('.ruby-version').read.strip.delete_prefix('ruby-') %>"
    BUNDLER_VERSION: "<%= Bundler::LockfileParser.new(Pathname.pwd.join('Gemfile.lock').read).bundler_version %>"
    RAILS_MASTER_KEY: "<%= ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY'] %>"
```

Answer (score 7):

`SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1` is introduced in Rails 7.1. This means you still need to provide the real `RAILS_MASTER_KEY`.

**For Rails 7.0.x**

Add this to Dockerfile, above the precompile line:

```
ARG RAILS_MASTER_KEY
ENV RAILS_MASTER_KEY=$RAILS_MASTER_KEY
```

Then you can remove `SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1` and leave just `RUN ./bin/rails assets:precompile`. This will create the ENV based on the arg MRSK passes when running the container.

**For Rails 7.1**

Use the newly introduced `SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1` which tells the precompile step to bypass the secret key base while precompiling.

Comment: thank you! I think this is correct. I will verify soon and mark it solved.

Comment: as the Dockerfile is in source control I think option #1 is insecure. Yes, the root of my problem is that I copied Dave Kiruma's (DriftingRuby) examples which opt-in to the Rails 7.1 default, and provided the Dockerfile this way, and I didn't realize SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 wasn't available in Rails 7.0 which I was testing on. I think I know what to do. Will get back to this tomorrow.

Comment: sure, option #1 is super insecure  but for testing/learning purposes can be an option.

Comment: Confirmed works. thank you!

Comment: I am editing your answer because while I understand what you say about testing/debugging, I think it's important that Stack overflow answers provide good guidance for others and not encourage things that are known to be insecure. It's too easy for someone to not know better and copy advice they find on this site.

Comment: I've been told that this solution is insecure because it will put the key into the docker image (haven't been able to confirm). please see discussion on https://github.com/mrsked/mrsk/pull/282

Comment: If you still need to use secrets in the build-time of Docker, you should use docker secrets with MRSK. It's described here https://github.com/mrsked/mrsk#using-build-secrets-for-new-images

BTW, using `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` in the build-time is not a good idea.

Comment: For Rails 7.0 we were able to simply use `RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE=DUMMY ./bin/rails assets:precompile` without injecting the master key for usage in docker build.

Comment: I've been stuck on this for days no days. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I even tried with a fresh rails install. Still getting the same error

Comment: What Rails version are you using?
Can you paste the error here? And the Dockerfile?

Comment: I've been stuck on this for days no days too. No solution works. My Rails is 7.1.2

Answer (score -1):

You would need to either add the master.key file on the deployed server, or add the key to ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY']
From what I've read in the mrsk readme.md, it uses the .env file, so you would need `RAILS_MASTER_KEY: 'your_master.key'` in your .env file

Comment: it's already in `.env`

Comment: As @gorka explained in the accepted answer, the problem is that the env setting isn't available in the Docker environment as builder arg, and since the precompile happens in Docker (not the running app), the presence or absence of the key in the running application is not relevant to the blocker. My primary concern is not doing something insecure, which committing the Rails master key to git is insecure.